# How to extract custom information from requests in Angular like Django?

Tags: django, angular, request

My question maybe is not clear enough because it's hard to compare between frontend and backend together however, I will try to explain it.

In Django, I can get key/value from requests whatever the type or the method of this request like: **request.POST** or **request.GET** ...etc.

In the same manner, I want to get the key/value from requests at this moment from Angular instead of Django, I want to create my custom logic by that.

Last thing I would like to say: this project is created not by Django but I want to use the same logic that Django uses in my situation.

Comment: Are you needing to access querystring information? or are you looking for a way to add data to a route that you can then access in a component?

Comment: actually, I want both, for example: if we assumed that I'm on one of pages that let me create a post, and after creating it, it will cast me to the home page then, I need to show a message telling me "this post has been created successfully". in that case, I need to set a new message and get this message in another url router

Comment: Resolvers can add information to routes. You'll want to look at using a service with Subject / BehaviorSubject properties to store / access data across components.

Comment: Injecting the ActivatedRoute into your component can get you access to information on the route like querystring parameters or segments, etc.

Comment: thx, @BrandonTaylor for your help I will investigate my research on this subject